How do I calculate p-value in this problem?
Random samples of resting heart rates are taken from two groups. Population 1 exercises regularly, and Population 2 does not. The data from these two samples is given below:
Population 1: $63, 72, 72, 72, 62, 68, 64$
$n_1 = 7$
$\bar x_1 = \frac{63 + 72 + 72 + 72 + 62 + 68 + 64}{7} = 67.57142857$
$S_1 = \sqrt{\frac{\sum{(x-67.57142857)^2}}{7-1}} = 4.5408201482824$
Population 2: $78, 77, 68, 69, 68, 71, 75, 68$
$n_2 = 8$
$\bar x_2 = \frac{78 + 77 + 68 + 69 + 68 + 71 + 75 + 68}{8} = 71.75$
$S_2 = \sqrt{\frac{\sum{(x-71.75)^2}}{8-1}} = 4.2678197846542$.
Is there evidence, at an $\alpha = 0.03$ level of significance, to conclude that there those who exercise regularly have lower resting heart rates? (Assume that the population variances are equal.) Carry out an appropriate hypothesis test, filling in the information requested.
What  is the value of the standardized test statistic?
$t_0 = \frac{(\bar x_1 - \bar x_2)-(\mu_1 - \mu_2)}{\sqrt{\frac{S_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{S_2^2}{n_2}}} = \frac{(67.57142857 - 71.75)-(0)}{\sqrt{\frac{4.5408201482824^2}{7}+\frac{4.2678197846542^2}{8}}} = -1.828497047$
What is the rejection region for the standardized test statistic?
Need degrees of freedom = d.f. = $\frac{(\frac{S_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{S_2^2}{n_2})^2}{\frac{S_1^4}{n_1^2(n_1-1)}+\frac{S_2^4}{n_2^2(n_2-1)}} = \frac{(\frac{4.5408201482824^2}{7}+\frac{4.2678197846542^2}{8})^2}{\frac{4.5408201482824^4}{7^2(7-1)}+\frac{4.2678197846542^4}{8^2(8-1)}} \approx 12 $
Level of significance $ = \alpha = 0.03$
$t_{v,\frac{\alpha}{2}} = t_{12,\frac{0.03}{2}} = t_{12,0.015} = \pm 2.8363$
Rejection region $ = (-\infty, -2.8363)\cup(2.8363, \infty)$
What is the p-value?
$2.8363$ corresponds to $0.0023$ on the z-table, $0.0023 \times 2 = 0.0046 = $ p-value since it is two-tailed.
Because the p-value $\leq \alpha$, $0.0046 \leq 0.03$, we reject $H_0$
Decision for hypothesis test?
I put all my work and reasoning with formulas to be as clear as possible, as I am not sure where I went wrong since I'm told at least one of the following is incorrect:

value of the standardized test statistic
rejection region for the standardized test statistic
p-value
decision for the hypothesis test

Any help is greatly appreciated, if more information is needed let me know although I've put the entire question here.

Hi all! If you down-vote or close-vote, please provide feedback to the OP as to how to improve their question. If your intent is to keep the site from sliding, votes do help some in that regard, but feedback does too!

Under the assumption that the group variances are equal but are unknown, the appropriate test statistic under the null hypothesis must used a pooled variance estimator.  Your statistic is based on the Welch-Satterthwaite test that does not assume equal population variances.
The correct statistic is provided in the Wikipedia article about the Student $t$-test:
$$T = \frac{\bar X_1 - \bar X_2}{s_p \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2}}},$$
where $$s_p = \sqrt{\frac{(n_1 - 1)s_1^2 + (n_2 - 1)s_2^2}{n_1 + n_2 - 2}}$$
is the pooled estimate of the standard deviation.

Your hypothesis is one-sided:
$$H_0 : \mu_1 = \mu_2 \quad \text{vs.} \quad H_1 : \mu_1 < \mu_2.$$
As such, the rejection region of the test must allocate the entire significance level $\alpha$ to the left tail of the Student's $t$-distribution, since if you observe $\bar X_1 > \bar X_2$, you immediately fail to reject $H_0$ because the data furnishes no evidence that the mean of population 1 is less than the mean of population 2.
The number of degrees of freedom for the 2-sample $t$-test with pooled variance is $\nu = n_1 + n_2 - 2 = 13$, so you want the $3^{\rm th}$ percentile of the Student $t$-distribution with $13$ degrees of freedom; i.e., the quantity $t$ such that $\Pr[T < t] = 0.03$.  If your test statistic is smaller than this quantity, you reject $H_0$.
The $p$-value of the test is $\Pr[T < -1.83665]$.

Using this formula I got -1.836647129 for my  standardized test statistic, however one of my answers is still considered wrong, did I make a mistake elsewhere?
Also, why did I get 2 downvotes? Did I ask the question wrong? Just asking so I can reformulate my question to be as clear as possible

@NoGo See the edits to my answer.  I cannot tell you why you were downvoted because I don't know why.

You wrote $ν=n_1+n_2−2=14$, however shouldn't it be $8 - 7 - 2 = 13$ or did you mean $ν=n_1+n_2−1=14$? How did you get 14 or is that typo

@NoGo Apologies, it is $\nu = 13$, not $14$.
